# PHP code to extract certificate from file pdf.p7m

Tags: php, pdf

I need to extract the certificate from a signed PDF file with a .p7m extension. I have no problem doing it with xml.p7m file but I can't do it with the pdf.p7m file. Following part of the code (working) to extract the certificate from xml file

```
// I receive the certified array
function der2smime($file)
{
$to=<<<TXT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=“smime.p7m”
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=“smime.p7m”
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
\n
TXT;
$from=file_get_contents($file);
$to.=chunk_split(base64_encode($from));
return file_put_contents("smime.p7m-b6m",$to);
}

$file = "prova.pdf.p7m";
$filenobom = "pr.pdf.p7m";

$str = file_get_contents($file);

$str = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$str);

file_put_contents($filenobom, $str);

$response = der2smime($filenobom);

$output = openssl_pkcs7_verify ("smime.p7m-b6m" , 0 , "pippo.crt" ,array("CA.pem"),"CA.pem","prova.pdf");
echo openssl_error_string();
$pemdata="pippo.crt";
$data = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($pemdata));
echo openssl_error_string();
print_r($data);
```

Comment: What's the difference between these two files? What do you mean by "I can't do it"?

Comment: Are you getting an error, or simply no data coming through? You need to be more explicit.

Comment: extracting the certificate from a file xml.p7m does its job if I try to extract it from a file pdf.p7m I find this error:    "0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data"   and I don't get the certificate

Comment: "A signed PDF file with a .p7m extension" is not a PDF file but a PKCS#7 container. I would guess that the container is shipped with the signed content (the PDF file itself). So you do not need to use the $content parameter. Maybe you need to convert it to a S/MIME format before if [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-verify.php#123118) comment is correct.

Comment: I entered my complete code that works with xml files and no with pdf